# php implode issue

Tags: php

I have an array $x = array(a,b,c); Each element of the array is a  url.

There is a function link($x[$i]) which converts every element of the array into a hyperlink.

```
function convert($x){
 $new = explode(',',$x);
 for($i=0;$i<count($new);$i++){
   echo  link($new[$i]);  // converts the url to hyperlink
 }
```

This displays the output as url1  url2 etc. But wht if i want the comma ',' between the 2 urls. How do i get that, without the comma ',' being part of the hyperlink?

desired output would be

```
hyperlink1 , hyperlink2 etc  // note comma ',' should not be part of the hyperlink
```

Comment: you want `array("a", "b", "c")` to be converted to `"a , b , c"` ?

Comment: @dmcnelis: that will append ',' at the end of each value. I don't want ',' after the last value.

Comment: @Dogbert: Not quite, What i need is to separate the elements which of the array which are urls in text form , convert them into hyper link using my link() function and then add a ',' between any very 2 urls.

Comment: Your convert function can't take an array (x) as a parameter because explode needs a string !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the array_map and implode functions to make this easy.

```
$urls = array('http://www.google.com/', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/');

$links = array_map("link", $urls);
echo implode(', ', $links);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = array(
  'http://google.pl',
  'http://yahoo.com',
  'http://msn.com'
);

function convert($array){
    $res = array();
    foreach ( $array as $url ) {
        $res[] = '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $url . '</a>';
    }
    return implode(', ', $res);
}

echo convert($x);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function convert($x){
 for($i=0;$i<count($new);$i++){
   echo  link($new[$i]) . ($i<count($new)-1?", ":"");  // converts the url to hyperlink
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function convert($x){
    return implode(',', array_map('link', explode(',',$x)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convert($x)
{
 $string = '';

 foreach($x as $element)
 {
   $string .= link($element).',';
 }

 $string = rtrim($string, ',');

 echo $string;
}
```

This to avoid the last link to have a comma at the end, as you want.
// echoes link1,link2,link3

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');

// then either:
$x = array_map('link', $x);

// or:
foreach ($x as &$value) {
    $value = link($value);
}

echo join(', ', $x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = '';
foreach (explode(',',$x) as $url)
  $output .= link($url);
$output = substr($output,0,-1);
echo $output;
```